# xsl sort not working as expected

Tags: sorting, xslt

I've the below XML and using XSLT2.0

```
 <A>
            <BID>Pt.IV</BID>
            <BID>Pt.III</BID>
            <BID>Pt.IIIA</BID>
            <BID>Pt.IIIB</BID>
            <BID>Pt.IIIC</BID>
            <BID>Pt.IIID</BID>
            <BID>Pt.IIIE</BID>
            <BID>Pt.IIIF</BID>
            <BID>Pt.IIIAA</BID>
            <BID>s.2(1)</BID>
            <BID>s.3</BID>
            <BID>s.3(1)</BID>
            <BID>s.3(2)</BID>
            <BID>s.3A</BID>
            <BID>s.3B</BID>
            <BID>s.4</BID>
            <BID>s.4(2)</BID>
            <BID>s.4(5)</BID>
            <BID>s.4(2A)</BID>
            <BID>s.4(4A)</BID>
            <BID>s.6(3)</BID>
            <BID>s.7</BID>
            <BID>s.7A</BID>
            <BID>s.8</BID>
            <BID>s.9</BID>
            <BID>s.12</BID>
            <BID>s.13</BID>
            <BID>s.20A</BID>
            <BID>s.20F</BID>
            <BID>s.20O</BID>
            <BID>s.20S</BID>
            <BID>s.20T</BID>
            <BID>s.20W</BID>
            <BID>s.21</BID>
            <BID>s.21(2)</BID>
            <BID>s.21(3)</BID>
            <BID>s.21(2A)</BID>
            <BID>s.21(4B)</BID>
            <BID>s.21(4C)</BID>
            <BID>s.21(4D)</BID>
            <BID>s.21B</BID>
            <BID>s.22(1)</BID>
            <BID>s.22(1)(b)</BID>
            <BID>s.22(4)</BID>
            <BID>s.23</BID>
            <BID>s.25(1A)</BID>
            <BID>s.27</BID>
            <BID>s.28</BID>
            <BID>s.31</BID>
            <BID>s.20O(2)</BID>
            <BID>s.20W(2)</BID>
            <BID>s.21B(1)</BID>
            <BID>s.21B(2)</BID>
            <BID>s.21B(3)</BID>
        </A>
```

here i'm trying to sort the values of BID using the below XSLT.

```
 <xsl:template match="A">
    <xsl:for-each select="BID">
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(.,'.')"/>
<table class="toa-entry">
                            <tbody>
<tr class="secondary-entry">
<td class="entry-name">
<xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                                    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

here the output that is get is as below.

[image]

But the expected is as below.

```
s2(1)
s3
s3(1)
s3(2) 
s3A 
s3B 
s4 
s4(2) 
s4(5) 
s4(2A) 
s4(4A) 
s6(3) 
s7 
s7A 
s8 
s9 
s12 
s13 
s20A 
s20F 
s20O 
s20O(2) 
s20S 
s20T 
s20W 
s20W(2) 
s21 
s21(2) 
s21(3) 
s21(2A)
```

here what's happening is, the sorting is working as first get all the numbers starts with 1, then 2, and so on.

where as i want it like in regular ascending order. 1,2,2a,3,3a and so on.

please let me know how i can get this output.

Here is working demo.

[DEMO](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJ9/4)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for awarding me the answer - however my solution didn't work. I'd prefer if you awarded it to a solution which did work, like @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't utilize a text sorting algorithm on numeric data.

Even though you have stripped out the characters, your data values are still text values.

If you require numeric sorting you need to tell the parser the data type of the data, which you can do using the [*data-type* attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp).

> data-type text | number | qname
>
> Optional. Specifies the data-type of the data to be sorted. Default is "text"

**EDIT**: Replace your regex with this: `[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]`

There is a limitation here because the regex strips all non-numeric characters out of the values. Therefore if the initial list is not already sorted correctly within the numeric factor, for example

- s.21(4B)
- s.21(4C)
- s.21(4D)

then the sorting will ignore the alphabetic component of the values.

Comment: Hi tom i've already tried it, i get the below. http://postimg.org/image/psf0qk8ib/. XPath i used is `<xsl:sort select="fn:replace(.,'([a-z]+\.)','')" data-type="number" />`

Comment: That's *almost* right. Whats the output of your regex?

Comment: The image i've linked above has the output, sorry, due to space constrain, i needed to make a image

Comment: No I mean the output looks almost correct. In fact it only starts to go wrong from *20O(2)*. I thought that maybe your regex was not behaving as expected.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please edit my Regex to get it done, please, i'm unable to understand it. here is the updated transformation http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJ9/3

Comment: The error i'm getting is starting from the beginning between `s.2(1)` and `s.3(1)` i need to get `s.3`, but it is kicked out to last

Answer (score 3):

You should try something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/A">
    <table >
        <xsl:for-each select="BID">
            <xsl:sort select="substring-before(., '.')" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="replace(substring-before(substring-after(concat(., '('), '.'), '('),'[A-Z]', '')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="replace(substring-before(substring-after(concat(., '('), '.'), '('),'[0-9]', '')" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="substring-after(., '(')" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The (rendered) **result**, when applied to your example:

```
Pt.III
Pt.IIIA
Pt.IIIAA
Pt.IIIB
Pt.IIIC
Pt.IIID
Pt.IIIE
Pt.IIIF
Pt.IV
s.2(1)
s.3
s.3(1)
s.3(2)
s.3A
s.3B
s.4
s.4(2)
s.4(2A)
s.4(4A)
s.4(5)
s.6(3)
s.7
s.7A
s.8
s.9
s.12
s.13
s.20A
s.20F
s.20O
s.20O(2)
s.20S
s.20T
s.20W
s.20W(2)
s.21
s.21(2)
s.21(2A)
s.21(3)
s.21(4B)
s.21(4C)
s.21(4D)
s.21B
s.21B(1)
s.21B(2)
s.21B(3)
s.22(1)
s.22(1)(b)
s.22(4)
s.23
s.25(1A)
s.27
s.28
s.31
```

Comment: Excellent usage of **sort** with **string** functions, +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Saxon, there is a collation you can request that treats any sequence of digits in the sort key as a number, so s12 sorts after s9.

```
collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?alphanumeric=yes"
```

It won't handle roman numerals though: sorting "App IX" after "App VIII" remains a challenge!